# Children in Enumeration

Tags: java, enumeration, children

I have a enumeration for elements in a JTree

When I find some specific element in this JTree, I want to check it's children. Do the method **children()** in a Enumeration check it's grandcildren too?

For example, let's supose this JTree, considering the identation as new levels of the tree:

- Fruits

  - apple
  - grape

    - orange
    - peach

      - pineapple
    - strawberry
  - banana

If I get the children of **grape**, will I have just **orange**, **peach** and **strawberry** or will I get **peach** children (**pineaple**) too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just get orange, peach and strawberry.  As a side note for future reference, this kind of behavior is almost a de facto.

Answer (score 1):

You will just have orange and peach - you would need to check them for their children (grandchildren of the original node).

---

Edit: As derivation noted, you will also get Strawberry as that is a first level child - but the grandchildren will not be included in the enumeration.

Comment: Think he will get strawberry too!